# Shutdown android device without system app / root access

Tags: javascript, android, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I'm currently creating a daemon for Vive Focus 3 VR headset to manage remotely a lot of devices.
No problem for rebooting the device, download/update/install others apps. But I can't find any solution to shutdown the headset.
Why is it possible to reboot the headset and no solution to shutdown the headset ?

in the manifest create a SecurityException "[..] is not a changeable permission type"

I can't have root access so code like below can't work :

> Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime()
> .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "reboot -p" });
> proc.waitFor();

Any suggestion ?